# How combine a @TargetRequestFilter with @RunWith(Parameterized.class)

Tags: java, pact

Is it possible annotate a method with @TargetRequestFilter in a test-class annotated with @RunWith(Parameterized.class)?

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class UserApiTest {
...
    @TargetRequestFilter
    public void addSessionCookieFilter(HttpRequest request) {
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, sessionCookie.toString());
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. `@TargetRequestFilter` requires `@RunWith(PactRunner.class)` to work, and you can only have one `@RunWith` annotation on the test.